# Background video in Xaringan slides

Tags: reveal.js, xaringan

I'm writing a presentation using Xaringan. I want to embed video such that when I transition to the slide containing the video it plays automatically in fullscreen. (i.e., I do not want to have to click on the video to play it).

I could achieve what I want using revealjs with:

```
## {data-background-video="my_video.mp4"}
```

but I've spent about 30 hours writing the presentation in Xaringan, including some custom css styles (I'm a complete css novice) so I don't want to convert to revealjs (especially as I haven't used revealjs other than to test the above).

Is there an equivalent in Xaringan? Given it's based on revealjs I assume it's possible but despite many hours on the internet I can't work out how.

Alternatively, is there a way to activate non-fullscreen video from a keyboard press. For example, like an incremental step that plays the video:

This doesn't work. It plays the audio upon a keypress but not the video:

```
---
--
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
    <source src="media/my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
---
```

This plays the audio at the start of the presentation (not from the slide I want) and there's no video (possibly because I have a background image set up on the first slide):

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay>
    <source src="media/my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Xaringan is based on `remark.js` not `reveal.js`.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @pat-s and the pages to which he linked, I have this working. In case it helps others, here's a working minimal example that autoplays audio and video (in fullscreen) upon slide transition.

The R Markdown is:

````
title: "Video Example"
author: "Andy Field"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: ["default", "my_styles.css"]
    includes:
      after_body: "afterInit.html"

---

# Minimal example of autoplaying audio and fullscreen video 

## Andy Field

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

---
class: inverse
background-image: url("http://www.metalmusicarchives.com/images/covers/dio-killing-the-dragon-20160817062111.jpg")
background-size: cover

<audio controls>
  <source src="http://www.discoveringstatistics.com/repository/misc/dio_killing_the_dragon.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="http://www.discoveringstatistics.com/repository/misc/dio_killing_the_dragon.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
</audio>


.center[Here's the audio.

It is a song by the band Dio.

Like many of their songs, it involves a dragon.

Next up, video.]

---
layout: false

<video width="100%" height="100%" controls id="my_video">
    <source src="http://www.discoveringstatistics.com/repository/misc/shrek_burp.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
````

Note that the YAML includes a reference to a file called "afterInit.html", which (in this case) is stored in the same directory as the markdown. This file contains the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var slideElements

  function getElementForSlide(slide) {
    slideElements = slideElements || document.querySelectorAll('.remark-slide')
    return slideElements[slide.getSlideIndex()]
  }

  slideshow.on('showSlide', function (slide) {
    Array.from(getElementForSlide(slide).querySelectorAll('video, audio')).forEach(function (vid) {
      vid.loop = false
      vid.currentTime = 0
      vid.play()
    })
  })

  slideshow.on('hideSlide', function (slide) {
    Array.from(getElementForSlide(slide).querySelectorAll('video, audio')).forEach(function (vid) {
      vid.pause()
    })
  })

</script>
```

The YAML also calls on a css file called 'my_styles' (also in the same directory as the markdown file), which is used to get the video to play fullscreen. I guess you could include this in a css chunk directly in the markdown, but I wanted to keep it external. The file contains:

```
#my_video {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

To get this to work, note that when I reference a video in the markdown I include `id="my_video"`.

This works for me when the presentation is in fullscreen in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! FOr me it does not work when I use a YouTube video

Comment: Presumably it won't work because you're linking to a URL not the mp4 file itself. Have you tried using [vembedr](https://ijlyttle.github.io/vembedr/), which is designed for embedding youtube vids within HTML?

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to have a YouTube video play automatically in full screen in xaringan slides and so far I have been unable.
Option 1->works but not fullscreen:
`<iframe width="1600" height="648" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0cXZv-8DiWA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Option 2 -> works but not fullscreen:
`library(vembedr)
embed_youtube("0cXZv-8DiWA") %>%
  use_start_time("10s") %>%
  use_align("center") %>%
  use_rounded(10)`

Comment: Option 3 -> full screen container, but no video: as in answer 
`layout: false

<video width="100%" height="100%" controls id="my_video">
    <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0cXZv-8DiWA" type="video/mp4">
</video>`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get a fully working solution in limited time, but you can use this is a start.

There are multiple issues already about this, both in `remark` and `xaringan`:
- https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/218
- https://github.com/gnab/remark/issues/322

`afterInit.html` should start `<script type='text/javascript'>` and end with `</script>` if I understand correctly.

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
institute: "RStudio, Inc."
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    includes:
      after_body: "afterInit.html"
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Sharingan_triple.svg)

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

---


<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MWnZ8SoMeHc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
````